# Change existing listview values at later stage

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview

I have an existing Listview in my app where user can choose a value before this is logged in my firebase app. Now I would like to edit the existing values to make it more clear to the user what the abbreviation means. Obviously once I do this and open an old entry for editing the app crashes since the old value is not part of the defined Listview values anymore.
Any way I can work around this?

Old List:

```
final List<String> subtypes = [
'AP',
'PE',
'TR',
];
```

New List:

```
final List<String> subtypes = [
'AP - Apple',
'PE - Peach',
'TR - Truck',
];
```

Following error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: AP.
flutter: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the structure to allow the data itself to be dynamic.

It's often beneficial to disassociate data from the key that stores it (DocumentId in Firestore). So if your list looks like this

```
abbreviations
   0: 'AP'
   1: 'PE'
   2: 'TR'
```

You can see if you change "AP" to something else, like "AP - Apple", it's a massive change and will break your code that depends on AP staying a string of "AP"

However if your structure is this

```
abbreviations
   -Y9jk90ijoaj9d //auto generated key/documentId
       abbr: "AP"
   -J8ijuai9jsijd
       abbr: "PE"
   -Niiojmsko0e0e
       abbr: "TR"
```

And anywhere you need to reference "AP", use the documentId (or key) of `-Y9jk90ijoaj9d`, then no matter what AP is changed to, it will always work because your code looks at the documentId `-Y9jk90ijoaj9d` instead of the actual string "AP".